# Blocked proxy response with status 403 to CONNECT in WebClient

Tags: android, https, chromium, webviewchromium

I am trying to perform a request in HTTPS through a WebClient in Android. It runs currently a on Galaxy Tab 2 (Android 4.2) and the application is Android 4.0.3 (API 15).

HTTPS requests work well on a WiFi connection but they are incredibly slow on a 3G connection and cause these messages to appear in LogCat

> 08-07 17:38:12.397: W/chromium(4566): external/chromium/net/http/http_proxy_client_socket.cc:274: [0807/173812:WARNING:http_proxy_client_socket.cc(274)] Blocked proxy response with status 403 to CONNECT request for [hostname:port].

I also send other HTTPS Post through a DefaultHttpClient and these requests are also very slow on HTTPS + 3G connection.

Any idea why and how to fix this?

Comment: increasing timeout? isn't code 403 -> Forbidden? what would the timeout change?

Comment: i think it get terminates before connecting ..

Comment: it was blocked by the ISP...

Comment: Is this issue resolved ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was blocked/throttled at the ISP level (3G/LTE provider). We contacted them to resolve the issue.